# How can I grant the account permission to list enabled APIs?

Tags: google-app-engine, permissions, google-cloud-build

During a build on Cloud Build, I get the following warning:

> Step #2: WARNING: Unable to verify that the Appengine Flexible API is enabled for project [xxxxx]. You may not have permission to list enabled services on this project. If it is not enabled, this may cause problems in running your deployment. Please ask the project owner to ensure that the Appengine Flexible API has been enabled and that this account has permission to list enabled APIs.

I'd like to get rid of this warning to get a clean build log.

Since the build succeeds, the problem must not be with Appengine Flexible API being disabled. No; the problem must be that the account does not have permission to list enabled APIs.

How can I fix that (either in the Console or at the command line)?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

To list the services available, you need the permission [`services.list`](https://cloud.google.com/service-usage/docs/access-control). You can grant this permission via [granting a role](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/granting-changing-revoking-access#granting_access_to_team_members) that includes said permission, like `roles/serviceusage.serviceUsageViewer`, or you can create [your own personalised role](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-custom-roles#creating_a_custom_role) with that permission only, if you wish to.

On how to enable the API: First check if said account has or hasn't said API enabled, which looks unlikely, with [`$ gcloud services list`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/services/list). By default, it shows all the enabled services for said account.

If you can't see 'appengineflex.googleapis.com' in said list, you can run [`$ gcloud services enable appengineflex.googleapis.com`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/services/enable) to do so.

Comment: _you need the permission `services.list`. You can directly grant that permission to the account to solve this._ How to do this isn't clear to me...

Comment: @jubobs Ey, sorry about that, I have edited my answer to include that bit.

Answer (score 0):

To verify your account and enable the API within the cloudbuild I had to add the account as `role/App Engine Deployer` and that worked on my case.
Also on another project I've created new SA and that I've added `Editor` permissions and that worked too. It was for testing purposes but it worked.

The steps to verify that it's working too below :

- `gcloud config set account youraccountname`
- `gcloud config set project yourprojectname`

Then :
- `gcloud auth activate-service-account yourname@yourproject.iam.gserviceaccount.com --key-file=yourfilekey.json`

Then to verify that it's working do : `gcloud services list` and you will see all the `NAME` and the `TITLE` of your services list.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue today. I needed to makes sure that billing was enabled on the project and my profile. I would check the Billing section for those that also see this issue.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the billing wasn't setup for the project I wanted to enable api. So I did:

From the navigation menu go Billing, go to your billing account, choose settings for the project and change the billing setting.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30009605)