# WARNING: Unable to verify that the Appengine Flexible API is enabled for project , App engine

Tags: php, laravel, google-cloud-platform, laravel-8

Hey I m trying to deploy laravel 8 project to google cloud app engine , but it seems to fail everytime throwing this error :

WARNING: Unable to verify that the Appengine Flexible API is enabled for project [####]. You may not have permission to list enabled services on this project. If it is not enabled, this may cause problems in running your deployment. Please ask the project owner to ensure that the Appengine Flexible API has been enabled and that this account has permission to list enabled APIs.
Beginning deployment of service [default]...

App.yaml:

```
runtime: php74
env: flex

runtime_config:
    document_root: public
# Ensure we skip ".env", which is only for local development
skip_files:
    - .env

automatic_scaling:
    min_num_instances: 1
    max_num_instances: 1

resources:
    cpu: 2
    memory_gb: 4
    disk_size_gb: 100

env_variables:
    # Put production environment variables here.
    APP_DEBUG: true
    APP_ENV: production
    APP_KEY: base64:##########################
    APP_NAME: "Marqly"

    LOG_LEVEL: debug
```

cloudbuild.yaml :

```
steps:
  - name: gcr.io/google.com/cloudsdktool/cloud-sdk
    args:
      - '-c'
      - |
        gcloud config set app/cloud_build_timeout 3600 \
        && gcloud app deploy -q --promote -v=$BUILD_ID \
        --project=$PROJECT_ID
    waitFor:
      - '-'
    entrypoint: bash
timeout: 3600s
```

Comment: Did u read the error message? Check settings and enable flexible api.

Comment: @Maksim thats the thing , the Appengine Flexible API is already enabled

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51915997/11251946