# How to fix APPLICATION_ERROR;google.iam.credentials.v1/CloudGaia.GenerateAccessToken;Account disabled: xxxxxxxx?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-app-engine, google-cloud-build, app-engine-flexible

I am getting the following error when deploying a service to Flexible app engine. This issue happened out of the blue and I have no clue what this CloudGaia. We checked the Flexbile App engine API and ensured that app engine is enabled. We also checked usage viewer permission which we never used before but now its an issue. Could someone give us some context regarding the Giaia generate Access token and the account disabled error. The details are listed below with the Permissions for the cloud build service account.

Cloud Build Error Messages:

**WARNING: Unable to verify that the Appengine Flexible API is enabled for project [******************]. You may not have permission to list enabled services on this project. If it is not enabled, this may cause problems in running your deployment. Please ask the project owner to ensure that the Appengine Flexible API has been enabled and that this account has permission to list enabled APIs.**

**ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) NOT_FOUND:  APPLICATION_ERROR;google.iam.credentials.v1/CloudGaia.GenerateAccessToken;Account disabled: xxxxxxxx**

API and Cloud build service account permissions:

[image: API Permission]
[image: IAM permissions]

Comment: Please check this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/roles#appengine.deployer) as you must also have the [Service Account User](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/service-account-permissions#user-role) (`roles/iam.serviceAccountUser`) role on the assigned App Engine [service account](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/configure-service-accounts), and the Cloud Build Editor (`roles/cloudbuild.builds.editor`), and Cloud Storage Object Admin (`roles/storage.objectAdmin`) roles on the project.

Answer (score 0):

Posting my comment as an answer.

Please check this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/roles#appengine.deployer) as you must also have the [Service Account User](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/service-account-permissions#user-role) (`roles/iam.serviceAccountUser`) role on the assigned App Engine [service account](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/configure-service-accounts), and the Cloud Build Editor (`roles/cloudbuild.builds.editor`), and Cloud Storage Object Admin (`roles/storage.objectAdmin`) roles on the project.

You could also check this related [Stack Overflow link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51912812/how-can-i-grant-the-account-permission-to-list-enabled-apis/51915997#51915997) wherein you need to check and add the needed permissions through gcloud CLI.

If the aforementioned steps did not work, I would suggest to file a bug through the [Google Cloud issue tracker](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers) so that cloud engineers could take a look at this. We don't have a specific ETA on this but you can keep track of its progress once the ticket has been created.